# Manusmriti Chapter 9 verse 94

Tags: manu-smriti

Manusmriti Chapter 9 Verse 94

> A man, aged thirty years, shall marry a maiden of twelve who pleases him, or a man of twenty-four a girl eight years of age; if (the performance of) his duties would (otherwise) be impeded, (he must marry) sooner.

I found this everywhere where I searched the translation of this verse. But, I saw only this translation. I want clarification. Is it truly written like the translation says?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The translation is correct.

Let's see the original sanskrit, along with two different translators texts.

> Verse 9.94
>
> त्रिंशद्वर्षो वहेत् कन्यां हृद्यां द्वादशवार्षिकीम् ।
> त्र्यष्टवर्षोऽष्टवर्षां वा धर्मे सीदति सत्वरः ॥ ९४ ॥
>
> > 94. A man thirty years old shall marry a charming maiden twelve years old; or one twenty four years old, a damsel eight years old; in the
> >     event of his duties suffering, he may do it sooner.
>
> ([English Translation](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201459.html) by Ganganath Jha)
>
> ---
>
> > 94. A man, aged thirty years, shall marry a maiden of twelve who pleases him, or a man of twenty-four a girl eight years of age; if
> >     (the performance of) his duties would (otherwise) be impeded, (he must
> >     marry) sooner
>
> ([English Translation](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu09.htm) by George Bühler)

However, it might be helpful to read this with the Medhātithi’s commentary (manubhāṣya):

> What the injunction means is that the maiden married should be so much
> younger than the man;—and not that marriage must be done only at. the
> age stated. Nor is any stress meant to be laid upon the exact number
> of years mentioned; **all that is meant is that one should many a girl
> very much younger than himself**.
>
> This injunction does not occur in the section dealing with Marriage;
> hence, what is stated here cannot he regarded as a qualification of
> the persons undergoing that sacrament, and consequently, as an
> essential factor in the rite itself; for this same reason, it cannot
> be taken as precluding the age of ‘ten’ or ‘twenty-five’ or such
> others.
>
> “But it is often found that even though laid down in a distinct
> passage, a detail does form an essential factor of an act”
>
> True; but the very fact that the teacher has thought it fit to place
> the present text apart from the section on marriage is clearly
> indicative of the fact that he had some special purpose in this.
>
> The practice of cultured men is also as we have stated.
>
> Further, **the age here stated can never be observed in the case of
> one’s son marrying a second time; so that, if the injunction were
> meant to be taken literally, it would mean that there should be no
> second marriage; and this would be absurd.—(94)**

- So according to Medhātithi’s interpretation of the above verse, it states the girl must be sufficiently younger compared to the male, the rule is not hard and fast, in regards to having the same age numbers as mentioned in the translation.

---

Similar verses are found in the other texts too, as added by Ganganath Jha in his comparative notes -

> Comparative notes by various authors:-
>
> Mahābhārata (13.41.14).—‘One who
> is thirty or twenty-one years old shall take a wife sixteen years old,
> but before she has attained puberty.’
>
> Viṣṇupurāṇa (Vīramitrodaya-Saṃskāra, p. 766).—‘A man shall select a
> wife whose age is one-third of his own.’
>
> Āpastamba (Do., p. 767).—‘A man thirty-years old shall take a wife ten
> years old, before she has attained puberty; and one twenty-one years
> old, a girl seven years old.’
>
> Āśvalāyana (Do.).—‘A maiden seven years old is called Śaiśavī; a man
> eighteen years of age shall marry her; a maiden eight years old is
> called Gaurī, conducive to richness of sons and grandsons; and she
> shall be married by a man twenty-five years old; a girl nine years old
> is called Rohiṇī conducive to richness of wealth; a wise man shall wed
> her for the accomplishment of all his desires; a girl over ten years
> age, until she has her courses, is called Gāndhārī; and she shall be
> married by a man desirous of living long.’

So, as per scriptures, it is valid to marry as prescribed, for that is the dharma.
Usually, the couple will have conjugal rights after the girl menarches and not before that.

Comment: Right age of Sexual intercourse ?

Comment: As per shastras and what I have heard, sexual congress may be done, after the girl completes her menarche. That is, she starts having a regular menstrual cycle.

Comment: Can you conclude is it right or wrong as per modern society? Because, child marriage is banned and sex before 18 is pedofile. A girl of age 13 is child.

Comment: Answer upvoted. " But also, about sexual intercourse, teenagers these days are consensually amply indulging in it. " it's true but " in some cases, the age difference is huge between them too " it's serious crime like child molestation.

Comment: We can't judge but at least we can say that was wrong because that makes us human.

Comment: Well, let me put it this way, in the context of present day times, whatever is against the Constitution is illegal and crime. But., from the worldview of Hinduism shastras they're the laws, and dharmika acts (righteous). One can ascribe any definition which may fit the glove of modern laws and constitutions. But, from religious perspective they're not a crime (adharma). Hope this clarify your doubts. :) @LeviAckerman

Comment: That means, according to shastras, marriage after puberty is sin? What a great conflict between Manusmriti and constitution!

Comment: Yes. A father who marries her daughter after her menarche incurs a sin of multiple Brahmahatyas. Constitution is National text, not religious, so conflicts are bound to happen @LeviAckerman.                                      If anything, maybe this verse will help you bring some balance in perspectives - [Manusmriti 4.176 says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu04.htm) 

_**Let him avoid** (the acquisition of) wealth and (the gratification of his) desires, if they are opposed to the sacred law, and **even lawful acts which may cause pain in the future or are offensive to men**._

Comment: I believe the age in which marriage consummates must be older in the Mahabharata during the age of Kali prophesizes that very young girls will be mothers and this is indeed seen as sinful. The wife may indeed choose her husband if the husband fails to marry her in time.

Comment: Also, dharma changes as stated above even practices like Niyogi within our scriptures are prohibited for this age.

Comment: Regarding reasoning I have best summed up here:

Comment: why child marriage was performed. Unwanted birth due to Gandharva marriage would be by lust was evil. When a child marries an older man there are years of waiting periods before the marriage can consumate. The father figure is replaced by the husband whom the wife trusts. This also tests if the husband can provide for the bride.
They also develop a non-sexual relationship before the marriage consummates, so birth would be of substance or meaning not simply a product of lust.

Comment: Not only does this marriage protect the wife from the harm of lust, but also tests the husband's worth what reason is this it must be praised, sadly today's world is full of lustful men and not those of a chivalrous nature, hence this practice must be dissolved until a new Yuga.

Comment: @Luffy regarding those bad men you mentioned above number one in today's society such urgent marriage is not needed since the situation has changed. Usually speaking also the female sadly is in some way forced to do so and the whole reason behind it is quite simply lust.

Comment: In Anusasanika parva it is mentioned that a woman must be happy in the household for it to prosper.

Comment: I think I will end with a final quote that Dharma has no care for personal preference it may change as society changes and has one goal the survival of society. In today's world, many of the crimes you mentioned are done based on one's personal preferences with lust, anger, and greed in mind. Back, then it was a simple nature of necessity and avoiding lustful marriage, that is why a father chose a groom for his daughter.

Comment: @Luffy I think you're confusing morals with ethics.

Answer (score -2):

**mostly this verses and rules was later added during invasion time in Bharat. That is why "Jauhar, sati-dawah, child marriage" was later added by that era's intellectuals. Because "Necrophilia and rape" was/is part of our peaceful invaders. this rituals is not commandments but self-imposed , one had the choice and liberty to reject.** Sanatana Dharma is based on seeking the truth. Does this single this never crossed your mind - **Only in Hinduism We do the Puja of Sakti(mother)**. Then how can that same dharma do bad to the woman ? do more research.
Recently woman warrior's skeleton and chariot have been discovered bi ASI in in  Sinauli. Swami Vivekananda have said in the past - in west women is girl while in east she is Mother.

Comment: Can you please add further information supporting your claim you cannot claim a verse is an interpolation without proof.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).